# how to install debian package from unsigned repository

Tags: debian, apt, deb

Trying to install Debian package to Debian 9 from unsigned repository:

```
# apt-get --allow-unauthenticated update
Get:1 http://files.freeswitch.org/repo/deb/freeswitch-1.8 stretch InRelease [3,196 B]
Hit:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Ign:1 http://files.freeswitch.org/repo/deb/freeswitch-1.8 stretch InRelease
Ign:3 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:4 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch Release
Fetched 3,196 B in 1s (1,940 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://files.freeswitch.org/repo/deb/freeswitch-1.8 stretch InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BD3189F5A2B57698
W: The repository 'http://files.freeswitch.org/repo/deb/freeswitch-1.8 stretch InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

But I need it. How can I do it? Thanx!

Answer (score 24):

In the sources.list entry for the untrusted repository, you can add "[trusted=yes]" (with the square brackets) between the first two elements of the entry, as in `deb [trusted=yes] http://...`

This will turn the error into a warning, as it has been default in past Debian releases, without having to completely disable signature verification

Comment: for who cannot find sources.list, you can find it at /etc/apt/

Comment: This is the Right Way if what you need to install isn't just a single deb from the repository.  You are committing to a potential security leak, but this way you're only opening yourself up to that one repository.

Comment: You can add more, eg:  `deb [arch=amd64 trusted=yes] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`

Answer (score 3):

In case this helps someone, you can one off install a deb file from the command line with:

```
sudo dpkg -i {filename}
```