# `Package '' has no installation candidate` when use `.iso` as debian 10 repo

Tags: bash, installation, debian, repository, debian-packaging

Read posts about how to use iso as repo in debian system,as [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61536712/issue-while-creating-a-local-apt-repo-for-installing-docker-on-ubuntu),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57710990/how-to-properly-add-a-source-in-sources-list),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562801/how-to-install-debian-package-from-unsigned-repository).

First,I downloaded 3 dvd .iso from debian 10 official site.
Then,

```
mkdir /media/cdrom1 /media/cdrom2 /media/cdrom3
mount -t iso9660 -o loop /home/mypc/Downloads/debian-10.9.0-amd64-DVD-1.256.c923fd.iso /media/cdrom1
apt-cdrom --no-mount -d=/media/cdrom1 add
mount -t iso9660 -o loop /home/mypc/Downloads/debian-10.9.0-amd64-DVD-2.256.b6990d.iso /media/cdrom2
apt-cdrom --no-mount -d=/media/cdrom2 add
mount -t iso9660 -o loop /home/mypc/Downloads/debian-10.9.0-amd64-DVD-3.256.6746e3.iso /media/cdrom3
apt-cdrom --no-mount -d=/media/cdrom3 add
```

Further,`vi /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb [trusted=yes] file:///media/cdrom1 buster contrib main
deb [trusted=yes] file:///media/cdrom2 buster contrib main
deb [trusted=yes] file:///media/cdrom3 buster contrib main
```

And `apt-get update`,output as below:

```
root@hp840:/home/mypc# apt-get update
Get:1 file:/media/cdrom1 buster InRelease
Ign:1 file:/media/cdrom1 buster InRelease
Get:2 file:/media/cdrom2 buster InRelease
Ign:2 file:/media/cdrom2 buster InRelease
Get:3 file:/media/cdrom3 buster InRelease
Ign:3 file:/media/cdrom3 buster InRelease
Get:4 file:/media/cdrom1 buster Release
Ign:4 file:/media/cdrom1 buster Release
Get:5 file:/media/cdrom2 buster Release
Ign:5 file:/media/cdrom2 buster Release
Get:6 file:/media/cdrom3 buster Release
Ign:6 file:/media/cdrom3 buster Release
Get:7 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib all Packages
Ign:7 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib all Packages
Get:8 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:8 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Get:9 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en
Ign:9 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en
Get:10 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:10 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Get:11 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main all Packages
Ign:11 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main all Packages
Get:12 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main amd64 Packages
Get:13 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en_US
Ign:13 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en_US
Get:14 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en
Ign:14 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en
Get:15 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib all Packages
Ign:15 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib all Packages
Get:16 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:16 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Get:17 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:17 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Get:18 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en
Ign:18 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en
Get:19 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:19 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main amd64 Packages
Get:20 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main all Packages
Ign:20 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main all Packages
Get:21 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en
Ign:21 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en
Get:22 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en_US
Ign:22 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en_US
Get:23 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:23 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Get:24 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib all Packages
Ign:24 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib all Packages
Get:25 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en
Ign:25 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en
Get:26 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:26 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Get:27 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:27 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main amd64 Packages
Get:28 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main all Packages
Ign:28 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main all Packages
Get:29 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en_US
Ign:29 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en_US
Get:30 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en
Ign:30 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en
Get:7 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib all Packages
Ign:7 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib all Packages
Get:8 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:8 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Get:9 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en
Ign:9 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en
Get:10 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:10 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Get:11 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main all Packages
Ign:11 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main all Packages
Get:12 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main amd64 Packages
Get:13 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en_US
Ign:13 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en_US
Get:14 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en
Ign:14 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en
Get:15 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib all Packages
Ign:15 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib all Packages
Get:16 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:16 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Get:17 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:17 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Get:18 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en
Ign:18 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en
Get:19 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:19 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main amd64 Packages
Get:20 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main all Packages
Ign:20 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main all Packages
Get:21 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en
Ign:21 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en
Get:22 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en_US
Ign:22 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en_US
Get:23 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:23 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Get:24 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib all Packages
Ign:24 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib all Packages
Get:25 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en
Ign:25 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en
Get:26 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:26 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Get:27 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:27 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main amd64 Packages
Get:28 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main all Packages
Ign:28 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main all Packages
Get:29 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en_US
Ign:29 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en_US
Get:30 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en
Ign:30 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en
Get:7 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib all Packages
Ign:7 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib all Packages
Get:8 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:8 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Get:9 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en
Ign:9 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en
Get:10 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:10 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Get:11 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main all Packages
Ign:11 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main all Packages
Get:12 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main amd64 Packages
Get:13 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en_US
Ign:13 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en_US
Get:14 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en
Ign:14 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en
Get:15 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib all Packages
Ign:15 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib all Packages
Get:16 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:16 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Get:17 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:17 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Get:18 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en
Ign:18 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en
Get:19 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:19 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main amd64 Packages
Get:20 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main all Packages
Ign:20 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main all Packages
Get:21 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en
Ign:21 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en
Get:22 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en_US
Ign:22 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en_US
Get:23 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:23 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Get:24 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib all Packages
Ign:24 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib all Packages
Get:25 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en
Ign:25 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en
Get:26 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:26 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Get:27 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:27 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main amd64 Packages
Get:28 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main all Packages
Ign:28 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main all Packages
Get:29 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en_US
Ign:29 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en_US
Get:30 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en
Ign:30 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en
Get:7 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib all Packages
Ign:7 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib all Packages
Get:8 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:8 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Get:9 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en
Ign:9 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en
Get:10 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:10 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Get:11 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main all Packages
Ign:11 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main all Packages
Get:12 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main amd64 Packages
Get:13 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en_US
Ign:13 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en_US
Get:14 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en
Ign:14 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en
Get:15 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib all Packages
Ign:15 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib all Packages
Get:16 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:16 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Get:17 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:17 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Get:18 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en
Ign:18 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en
Get:19 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:19 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main amd64 Packages
Get:20 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main all Packages
Ign:20 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main all Packages
Get:21 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en
Ign:21 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en
Get:22 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en_US
Ign:22 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en_US
Get:23 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:23 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Get:24 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib all Packages
Ign:24 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib all Packages
Get:25 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en
Ign:25 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en
Get:26 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:26 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Get:27 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:27 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main amd64 Packages
Get:28 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main all Packages
Ign:28 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main all Packages
Get:29 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en_US
Ign:29 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en_US
Get:30 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en
Ign:30 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en
Get:7 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib all Packages
Ign:7 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib all Packages
Get:8 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:8 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Get:9 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en
Ign:9 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en
Get:10 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:10 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Get:11 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main all Packages
Ign:11 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main all Packages
Get:12 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main amd64 Packages
Get:13 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en_US
Ign:13 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en_US
Get:14 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en
Ign:14 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en
Get:15 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib all Packages
Ign:15 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib all Packages
Get:16 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:16 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Get:17 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:17 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Get:18 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en
Ign:18 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en
Get:19 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:19 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main amd64 Packages
Get:20 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main all Packages
Ign:20 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main all Packages
Get:21 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en
Ign:21 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en
Get:22 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en_US
Ign:22 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en_US
Get:23 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:23 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Get:24 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib all Packages
Ign:24 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib all Packages
Get:25 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en
Ign:25 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en
Get:26 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:26 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Get:27 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:27 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main amd64 Packages
Get:28 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main all Packages
Ign:28 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main all Packages
Get:29 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en_US
Ign:29 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en_US
Get:30 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en
Ign:30 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en
Get:7 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib all Packages
Ign:7 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib all Packages
Get:8 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:8 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Get:9 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en
Ign:9 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en
Get:10 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:10 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Get:11 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main all Packages
Ign:11 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main all Packages
Get:12 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main amd64 Packages
Get:13 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en_US
Ign:13 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en_US
Get:14 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en
Ign:14 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/main Translation-en
Get:15 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib all Packages
Ign:15 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib all Packages
Get:16 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:16 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Get:17 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:17 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Get:18 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en
Ign:18 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en
Get:19 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:19 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main amd64 Packages
Get:20 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main all Packages
Ign:20 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main all Packages
Get:21 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en
Ign:21 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en
Get:22 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en_US
Ign:22 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/main Translation-en_US
Get:23 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:23 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Get:24 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib all Packages
Ign:24 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib all Packages
Get:25 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en
Ign:25 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en
Get:26 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:26 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Get:27 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main amd64 Packages
Ign:27 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main amd64 Packages
Get:28 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main all Packages
Ign:28 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main all Packages
Get:29 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en_US
Ign:29 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en_US
Get:30 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en
Ign:30 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/main Translation-en
Get:7 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib all Packages
Ign:7 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib all Packages
Get:8 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Err:8 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
  File not found - /media/cdrom1/dists/buster/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages (2: No such file or directory)
Get:9 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en
Ign:9 file:/media/cdrom1 buster/contrib Translation-en
Get:15 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib all Packages
Ign:15 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib all Packages
Get:16 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Err:16 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
  File not found - /media/cdrom2/dists/buster/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages (2: No such file or directory)
Get:17 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:17 file:/media/cdrom2 buster/contrib Translation-en_US
Get:23 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Err:23 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib amd64 Packages
  File not found - /media/cdrom3/dists/buster/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages (2: No such file or directory)
Get:24 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib all Packages
Ign:24 file:/media/cdrom3 buster/contrib all Packages
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch file:/media/cdrom1/dists/buster/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages  File not found - /media/cdrom1/dists/buster/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/media/cdrom2/dists/buster/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages  File not found - /media/cdrom2/dists/buster/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/media/cdrom3/dists/buster/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages  File not found - /media/cdrom3/dists/buster/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages (2: No such file or directory)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Finally,

```
root@hp840:/home/mypc# apt-get install aide
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package aide is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'aide' has no installation candidate
```

What's the problem when use `.iso` as debian 10 repo?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> File not found - /media/cdrom1/dists/buster/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages (2: No such file or directory)

You need to remove `contrib` component from your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb [trusted=yes] file:///media/cdrom1 buster main
deb [trusted=yes] file:///media/cdrom2 buster main
deb [trusted=yes] file:///media/cdrom3 buster main
```

The Debian DVDs contains only the free Software.

To install `aide` package, you need to add the `debian-10.9.0-amd64-DVD-6` to your `sources.list`.

The `debian-10.9.0-amd64-DVD-6` [is available here](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/jigdo-dvd/), it can be downloaded through `jidgo`. See [Downloading Debian CD images with jigdo](https://www.debian.org/CD/jigdo-cd/index.html).

To know the content of Debian DVDs you need to download and extract the `*.list.gz` [file from here](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/list-dvd/). Every file will give the list of packages are contained in each Debian ISO.

Comment: Then,How to install package like `aide` through .ISO file?